# Securing ARP3 - AutoResponse Plus installation against SQL injection attacks

Tags: sql, code-injection

I am using a auto responder email software (AutoResponse Plus - ARP3). This is a perl script installed in cgi-bin directory. Last week someone hacked into the software & sent tons of spam emails using this software from my server. Little research revealed that this software has no mechanism to prevent SQL injection.

If you are in the same boat contact the vendor for a fix. As it appears there is no simple solution to fix it 100% since this software's source code is minified & obfuscated.

Comment: The program example you have shown was purposefully minified & obfuscated. Before working on it, one would have to deparse and untangle it.

There is no magic bullet to prevent SQL injection, except: Variables should never be interpolated into SQL queries. Instead, placeholders can be used. If the code uses the DBI interface, changing the code so that it uses placeholders might be quite easy.

But this can't be done with a few simple extra lines at a top.

Comment: Run `perl -p 's/\"(\\x\w\w)+\"/$&/gee' the_script` and it will be a lot less unreadable.

Comment: If you're familiar with php, why not create a wrapper php CGI script which reads the POST variables and then creates a suitable CGI environment (i.e. setting some environment variables, REQUEST_METHOD="GET", QUERY_STRING="...") for the obfuscated perl script?

Comment: I ran this command 
# perl -p 's/\"(\\x\w\w)+\"/$&/gee' arp3-new.pl
in the shell & got errors
Can't open perl script "s/\"(\\x\w\w)+\"/$&/gee": No such file or directory

Comment: @Vij mob forgot a flag, it should be `perl -pe`, not `perl -p`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. perl -pe 's/\"(\\x\w\w)+\"/$&/gee' the_script worked! but when I copied the output to the actual script & tested it out I got bunch of errors & message: aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: I am not sure how to create a PHP wrapper when the attack is directly aimed at the perl script

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be very confused. An injection error is a coding error, not a validation issue. It's the failure to convert text into an appropriate literal when generating code.

For example,

```
my $stmt = "
   SELECT *
     FROM Table
    WHERE $field='$value'
";
```

should be

```
my $stmt = "
   SELECT *
     FROM Table
    WHERE ".$dbh->quote_identifier($field)."=".$dbh->quote($value)."
";
```

or

```
my $stmt = "
   SELECT *
     FROM Table
    WHERE ".$dbh->quote_identifier($field)."=?
";
# Followed by ->execute($value) instead of ->execute()
```

Comment: How can I use this suggestion when the script is obfuscated?

Comment: One of the problems of closed-source software is that you can't fix it yourself. You'll have to talk to whoever you licensed the script from.